# Mutation Observer - get span from addedNodes.children

Tags: javascript, mutation

I can't use numbers because there might be something before the span like a timestamp.

```
console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].children);
```

Gives me this

```
HTMLCollection(4) [span, button.chat-line__username, span, span]
0:span.chat-line__message--badges
1:a.chat-author__display-name
2:span
3:span.message
length:4
__proto__:HTMLCollection
```

I want to store `a.chat-author__display-name` inside a variable. What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: An HTMLCollection is just an array-like object - just reference the index you want. `mutation.addedNodes[0].children[1]`

Comment: I can't use numbers, i need to get it by it's class name.

Comment: @oban_internet,did you see`HTMLCollection(4) [span, button.chat-line__username, span, span]` not equal to the result you see down `1:a.chat-author__display-name`

Comment: @oban_internet,show your html?

Comment: Hey, i just went back to previous version of the script and your solution works i just messed up somewhere. Thanks a lot, can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the HTMLCollection to find the first element that matches.

```
const authorAnchor = [...mutation.addedNodes[0].children]
  .find(child => child.className === 'chat-author__display-name');
```

Comment: That's not it either. It returns undefined. Did you intentionally put three dots in there? I tried with and without them but i still get undefined.

Comment: If it doesn't work. your actual HTML must not match what you posted in your question. Yes, those dots are array spread syntax, they convert an array-like object into an array.

Comment: You're right i messed up. Thanks for the help anyways. I will take a note of You using "Array spread syntax".

Answer (score 0):

Using `mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelector('.chat-author__display-name')` solved my problem.